# Editing a (conf) json file using a template or tool

Tags: json, templates, editing

I have a configuration file that is frequently modified by different people.
This conf file is necessary for our application to be running correctly.

However, modifying it is annoying due to the fact it is ugly.

And for now, we've all been using Notepad++ but it sometimes happen that we make a mistake when we modify it and accidentally delete a comma or something that makes the file not valid.

So I'm looking for a tool or template or something so that modifying this file becomes **easier** and **safer**.

It looks like :

```
    "computers": {

    "GA013773L": { "version": "1.41.3",  "environment": "Development", "owner":"peter" , "platform":"x64", "admin":"true"},

    "GA044611L": { "version": "1.43.5",  "environment": "Production", "owner":"john" , "platform":"x64", "admin":"true"},

    .....
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If several people is modifying the JSON file I recommend you to create and Excel file and then a script to get the information from that Excel file and convert it to JSON. This is not very hard to implement and it can save you a lot of time since almost everybody is used to work with Excel files.

On the other hand, there are plenty of tools to modify JSON files without having to open a text editor. Exemple:
https://jsoneditoronline.org/

I hope it helps.

Comment: I'll look into the Excel tip if I don't find any solution, thanks